# xpath for foreach loop

Tags: c#, xpath, foreach

I have a foreach loop to parse html and i am using xpath for it. What i need is following

```
<p class="section">sectiontext1</p>
<p class="subsection">subtext1</p> ----need this in first loop
<p class="subsection">subtext2</p>  ---need this in first loop
<p class="section">sectiontext2</p>
<p class="subsection">subtext11</p> ---need this in second loop
<p class="subsection">subtext22</p>  ---- need this in second loop
<p class="section">sectiontext3</p>

foreach (HtmlNode sectionNode in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='section']"))
        {
            count=count+2;
            string text1 = sectionNode.InnerText;

            foreach (HtmlNode subSectionNode in htmldocObject.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='subsection'][following-sibling::p[@class='section'][1] and preceding-sibling::p[@class='section'][2]]"))
            {
                string text = subSectionNode.InnerText;
            }

        }
```

what i am trying to do is loop through the sections and find each subsections under the specific section, do some processing and then move to the next section to find the subsections under that particular section.

Comment: `I have a foreach loop to parse html and i am using xpath for it.` Please show us that code.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with xpath?  Are you using `XSLT`, `XPathNavigator` or `LINQ to XML`?

Comment: @mjwills updated the post to add the foreach loop code

Comment: @Matthew Whited - I am using HTMLAgility pack in my .net c# app. What I want to do is web scrape a regulations content and dump it to excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the XPath to work correctly since you can't reference variables... but you can fix your query with `LINQ`.

```
foreach (var section in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='section']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(section.InnerText);
    foreach (var subSection in section?.SelectNodes("following-sibling::p")
                                      ?.TakeWhile(n => n?.Attributes["class"]?.Value != "section")
                                      ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + subSection.InnerText);
}
/*
sectiontext1
        subtext1-1
        subtext1-2
sectiontext2
        subtext2-11
        subtext2-22
sectiontext3
*/
```

... if you aren't using VS2015+ ...

```
foreach (var subSection in (section.SelectNodes("following-sibling::p") ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
                                   .TakeWhile(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value != "section"))
```

... same thing in XSLT ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template  match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="//p[@class='section']">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::p[@class='subsection'][preceding-sibling::p[@class='section'][1]=$start]">
            <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="text()"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with the following xpath - .//p[@class='section-e'][" + count + "]/following-sibling::p[@class='subsection-e' and count(preceding-sibling::p[@class='section-e'])=" + count + "]    Where count is the number of section tags passed. But I liked your linq version more to the point and concise.